# View user list by number of badges awarded

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges

[Listing users in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=all&sort=reputation) provides a quick way to show a user list by reputation score, but on a site where metrics are a integrated feature, I'm surprised there's no way to see any list by number of badges awarded. You could have a very high rep, but comparatively few badges. Sometimes it's interesting to stalk those with giant reps to see just how they've earned them, but I'd also be interested in seeing who has managed to qualify for the most badges.

Apart from general curiousity there's little functional advantage to this feature, although I'm sure aspirational users would get a lot out of seeing a list of badge-winning 'all stars' they can aim for.

Comment: But badges aren't just a numeric value. Each badge has a different condition and method of acquisition. I don't think it's really comparable to rep in that aspect.

Comment: They are rather numeric, given that each profile thumbnail shows the numbers of each on a tri-scale of perceived difficulty to obtain. I'd be very interested to see who has the most gold badges, for whatever reason. Useless but interesting.

Comment: a) Who has most gold badges: see d). b) Who has most silver badges: see d). c) Who has most bronze badges: see d). d) Who has most rep: see e). e) Who is Jon Skeet?